# Can’t make /etc/fstab writable with chmod

Tags: linux, fstab

I am following the second answer to the post (https://askubuntu.com/questions/178712/how-to-increase-swap-space) to increase swap space but whenever I run ‘’’sudo chmod +w /etc/fstab’’’ I still see “/etc/fstab is unwritable” when I go to change the document. I have tried to change the immutability of /etc/fstab with chattr but this has not been successful. How can I make changes to /etc/fstab? Thanks.

Comment: (1) "Second answer" is ill-defined, as each user can choose sorting. If you want to refer to an answer, link directly to the answer ("share" under the answer). (2) You say "I have tried to change the immutability of `/etc/fstab` with `chattr` but this has not been successful" and then in your answer you do *exactly* this, successfully. What? Apparently your failed try did something differently. The lesson is you should always post exact commands you use, error messages (if any), not only your description or interpretation. If you posted the wrong command, then maybe you would get actual help.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my question - you have to run

```
chattr -i /etc/fstab
```

then run

```
sudo chmod +w /etc/fstab
```

then run

```
sudo nano /etc/fstab
```

and you can write to `/etc/fstab` (and probably other files meant to be immutable!).

Comment: Please come back two days later and check as answered.